# Workbook split hangs up here

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, worksheet

**The project:** It deals with very sensitive HR/performance data, and I need to send 1000s of employees' data to their individual managers (about 100 managers who can only see their team's data, and no one else's), so I need about 100 files split (1 for each manager).

**The file:** - Many different tabs, separated by role. - First column is a unique identifier made by concatenating the Manager's name with the job title ex. John Stevens_Office Manager

**The task:** John Stevens will have team members in many different job roles, and needs all that data in one file, separated into tabs by job role.

[image]

Based on that sample data, the ideal macro would give me 3 files with 3 worksheets in each, and 1 row of data in each worksheet. However, I will settle for the worksheet being split into multiple files.

Here is my code.

```
    Sub SplitWB()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveWorkbook.Save

Dim OutputFolderName As String
 OutputFolderName = ""
    Set myDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    myDlg.AllowMultiSelect = False
    myDlg.Title = "Select Output Folder for Touchstone Files:"
    If myDlg.Show = -1 Then OutputFolderName = myDlg.SelectedItems(1) & "\" Else Exit Sub
    Set myDlg = Nothing

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Dim d As Object, c As Range, k, tmp As String, unique(500)
    i = 0

    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1))
        tmp = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(tmp) > 0 Then d(tmp) = d(tmp) + 1
    Next c

    For Each k In d.keys
        Debug.Print k, d(k)
         i = i + 1
         unique(i) = k
    Next k

    UniqueCount = i

'start deleting

For i = 1 To UniqueCount

    'Actions for new workbook
    wpath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    wbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    wsheet = ActiveSheet.Name

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=OutputFolderName & unique(i), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    For j = 1 To lastRow
        If Range("A" & j) <> "" And Range("A" & j) <> unique(i) Then
            Rows(j).Delete
            j = j - 1
        End If
    Next

    'hide helper columns

'    If HideC = False And DeleteC = True Then
        Columns("A:D").Hidden = True
'    End If
'


    Range("E8").Select


    'Select Instructions tab
    'Worksheets("Guidelines").Activate

    'Save new workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Workbooks.Open (wpath)

    'ActiveWorkbook.Close False

    Workbooks(wbook).Activate

Next


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox ("Macro has completed successfully!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Generated files can be found in the following directory:" & vbNewLine & OutputFolderName)

End Sub
```

The code hangs at "If Range("A" & j) <> "" And Range("A" & j) <> unique(i) Then"

It is located about half-way into the code and the chunk starts with "For j = 1 To lastRow"

Please help. It will literally save me a day's work or more. Thanks!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "hangs"?

Comment: Another note Loop backwards `For j = lastRow to 1 step -1` and get rid of the `j = j - 1`

Comment: You just have `dim unique(500)`, perhaps you need to make sure it's set to a certain type? (Long or String?) You should also qualify the `Range()` to include the sheet it's on: `wsheet.Range("A"&j)...`

Comment: @ScottCraner It gives me a debug error but no explanation

Comment: As I asked @m5edward (who is posting the identical code, with what seems like the identical problem) `In the workbook that works, does column A contain text values? In the workbook that doesn't work, does column A contain numeric values?` and I pointed out that the comparison of a string value with a numeric value causes the code to fail. (Verified when I tested it.)

Comment: No, I take that back, m5edward's code has the line `Columns("A:D").Hidden = True` commented out, whereas edwards_mark_86's code doesn't.  And m5edward sets `Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False` while code is running.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
For j = lastRow to 1 step -1
    If Range("A" & j) <> "" And Range("A" & j) <> unique(i) Then
        Rows(j).Delete
    End If
Next
```

instead. This allows you to loop backwards so when you delete a row it won't lose track of where you want `j` to be in the loop.

Comment: Looks like it works, but I won't know until I run like all 50 tabs in the workbook lol. Thanks for your help! I will keep you posted!